# Is there a Magento event for deducting stock? For pack creation

Tags: product, event-observer, stock

is there a Magento event for deducting stock?

We are creating a pack of products (say 1 pack of 6 bottles). Product title and image show 6 bottles. So customer would select 1 prtoduct qty from the dropdown on the product page when ordering. Also in the cart one would expect to see: 1 pack (of 6 bottles)

But when we reserve and deduct the stock we need the qty to be 6 bottles. I mean: that is the real wty being sold. 1 pack of 6 bottles.

Now editing QTY value is not the best solution because it would show as qty = 6 in cart (and customer expects 1 pack, so 1 as a number). Also the pricing is multiplied when we multiple QTY value by 6.

**So my question is**: is there an event or method we could attach to that allows us to show QTY = 1 everywhere .... but when stock is decreased and the sale is made that the QTY = 6?

I hope this is clear

Help appreciated

Comment: The answer is "no", but it's possible to add this event with a little rewrite, see my anser in the linked duplicate.

Comment: With the "before" event in my code you could use `$items = $observer->getItemsObj()->getItems(); ` to retrieve the stock items, then manipulate `$items` and pass it back with `$observer->getItemsObj()->setItems($items);` so that the changed qtys will be saved.